# Error: Guard will not detect changes to your Gemfile (Ruby gem)

Tags: ruby, bundler, guard, gemfile, gemspecs

I am trying to use Guard as a help for make Test Driven Development using `Vim` in Linux Shell. For add Guard dependecy, i added this to my `.gemspec` file:

```
spec.add_development_dependency "guard"

spec.add_development_dependency "guard-rspec"

spec.add_development_dependency "guard-bundler"
```

Then, in Command Line, i executed this:

```
sudo bin/setup

bundle exec guard init
```

Then for update `Bundle` gems and dependencies, i updated Bundle for take in count Guard files:

```
sudo bundle install
```

When i tried to use Guard with `bundle exec guard`, i got this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::VERSION
/var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.1/lib/did_you_mean/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb:63: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::JaroWinkler::WEIGHT
/var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.1/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb:63: warning: previous definition of WEIGHT was here
```

And for Guard output this warning:

```
 Error: Guard will not detect changes to your Gemfile!
> [#] 
> [#]   Solution: move the Gemfile to a watched directory and symlink it back.
```

I am searching a solution for this problem in `guard` public repository in Github, but until now i was unable to fix it.

Version of `Ruby` i am using : `ruby 2.6.5`

Version of `guard`: `2.16.1`

`Bundler` version : 2.0.2

[Here you can see Gemfile,Guardfile and gemspec](https://github.com/Alien-97/Gemfile)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The error seems clear. Where is your .gemspec in relation to wherever you're running Guard from, and what's in your Guardfile?

Comment: Hello @ToddA.Jacobs, I edited my question for you can see in GitHub repo .gemspec,Guardfile and gemfile setup files. Thanks

Comment: Someone else have any idea about how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance